# Where can I find storm-kafka (kafka spout) topology working example?

Tags: cloud, bigdata, apache-storm

In the new version of storm (0.9.2) there is a build-in kafka spout based on https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/tree/v0.9.2-incubating
There are many examples of how to use this kafka spout on the net but looks like something was changed.
most example doesn't work, many errors due to unknown declarations.

for example:

```
BrokerHosts brokerHosts = KafkaConfig.StaticHosts.fromHostString(
                ImmutableList.of("localhost"), 1);
```

'StaticHosts' is not recognized by the compiler, KafkaConfig class doesn't contain it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this link: [Integrating Kafka and Storm](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/05/27/kafka-storm-integration-example-tutorial/). The author says that [kafka-storm-starter](https://github.com/miguno/kafka-storm-starter) project should contain examples which you can use in your own projects. And he says that the storm-kafka spout they use is the same as in storm 0.9.2. However, I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have any experience with Kafka and I'm also experimenting but you might want to try 
the code snippet below to overcome the problem stated:

```
GlobalPartitionInformation partitionInformation = new GlobalPartitionInformation();
partitionInformation.addPartition(0, Broker.fromString("localhost"));
BrokerHosts host = new StaticHosts(partitionInformation );
```